# В PyCharm community установить модуль coverage для тестирования кода Python?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, pycharm, python-unittest, code-coverage

У меня бесплатная версия PyCharm, однако для учебного задания надо протестировать покрытие кода инструментом *Coverage*, который есть только в платной версии программы. Прочитал, что для этого можно использовать сторонний модуль *coverage*, который для моего Python уже установлен. Однако при попытке добавить модуль в проект PyCharm (без виртуального окружения) получаю ошибку:

```
Executed command: pip install --user coverage
Error occurred: Non-zero exit code (2)
Command output:
Usage:   
  C:\Users\zlatt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  C:\Users\zlatt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  C:\Users\zlatt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  C:\Users\zlatt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  C:\Users\zlatt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --build-dir
```

Диалоговое окно с ошибкой показал на скрине
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что можно предпринять? Спасибо

Comment: Какие версии PyCharm и pip у вас?

Comment: попробуйте сделать это в командной строке , типа coverage run -m pytest ....  либо pytest --cov   с модулем pytest-cov

Comment: @СергейКох, версия PyCharm 2019.3.4, версия pip - 23.1.2

Comment: @nexoma, пробовал, только для unittest - не получилось

Comment: установите этот модуль от администратора

Comment: Попробуйте обновить pycharm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085956/pycharm-venv-failed-no-such-option-build-dir